# Tab colors in ProdPowerTools using RegEx and full file path

Tags: visual-studio, colors, tabs, productivity-power-tools

I've just installed PPT on VS2010. There is ability to color tab by project and by reg.ex. (of file name). May be anyone knows is it possible to color also by full file name/path?

for example: I have two files "Index.cshml" one placed in the "User\" subfolder and one in the "Products\". 
If I set up color Reg.Ex as ".*User.*" then only those files will be colored that have "User" in their names : "Controolers\UserController.cs" but not an "Views\User\Index.cshml"

Answer (score 1):

There is Settings to use full document path for regex.
[image: PPT Options]